# Javascript forEach callback

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm diving into Javascript callbacks and stuff. I came around the forEach() function. The functioname says it all, loop through each object in a list.

When I look into the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) I see the following syntax:

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

And the documentation also mentions the parameters

```
currentValue
index
array
```

I stumbled upon an easy example of a forEach implementation:

```
var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];

friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
     console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName);
});
```

And this gives me the obvious output:

```
 "1. Mike"
 "2. Stacy"
 "3. Andy"
 "4. Rick"
```

I can live with the behaviour about everything and the result it gives, but I want to know why this is working and I'm confused about this

```
...function (eachName, index)...
```

When and where or how are eachName and index being filled with the correct value? Or how can I see how **forEach** is implemented, cause I'm guessing that this one is doing the magic here? Or am I missing an important concept here?

Comment: ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification -> [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach), or in the annotated [ES5](https://es5.github.io#x15.4.4.18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) that you provided, you find the answer:

The three parameters (`currentValue, index, array`) are the parameters of the callback function (`arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg]`). To display it in your example:

```
var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];

friends.forEach(function (currentValue, index){
     console.log(index + 1 + ". " + currentValue);
});
```

So when forEach is run, a lot of things happen ([have a look at the polyfill on the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)), but at some point, forEach will loop through the items in the array and call the callback you provided, with the arguments mentioned above. A simplified version would be:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {
    // ...
    for(let i = 0; let i < this.length; i++) { // "this" refers to your array here
        // Here the arguments are passend in:
        // currentValue = this[i]
        // index = i
        // array = this
        callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a **simplification** of an actual `.forEach()` implementation, only to give the basic idea of what's happening.

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function( callback ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i ) {
        callback( this[i], i, this );
    }
};
```

Basically it loops through the array and calls the function with the correct parameters at each iteration.

The actual implementation is engine-specific and (most likely) not native JavaScript.